# What replaced asio::tcp::resolver::query?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I'm currently trying to build a project without any deprecated methods and hit a problem with the resolver. My old code used to look like this:

```
const asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(params.host, std::to_string(params.port));
      m_resolver.async_resolve(query, [&](const std::error_code &ec_, asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iter) {
        if (ec_) {
          ec = ec_;
          return;
        }
        while (iter != asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator()) {
          m_socket.reset(new asio::generic::stream_protocol::socket(m_service));
          m_socket->async_connect((*iter++).endpoint(), [&](const std::error_code &err_code) {
            if (err_code) {
              ec = err_code;
              return;
            }
            connected = true;
          });
        };
      });
```

But now Asio says asio::tcp::resolver::query is deprecated. How is hostname resolution done now?

Comment: Have you read any boost documentation about this? What did it tell you?

Comment: Not much. Says its deprecated but doesn't say what replaced it: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/query.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing replaced it. Just look at the [documentation of `[async_]resolve`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve.html) on what to use instead:

[image]

Basically, the "parameter object" was "inlined" to separate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed pretty confusing. But the `resolve()` as several overloads, [some of which are deprecated and some overloads are not](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.28.0/doc/asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve.html). And even the examples that are part of the Asio / Boost Asio repository are still using the deprecated query. Which doesn't help adoption of course.

For full completeness, this could be the new way of using the Asio library (non-boost version):

```
asio::io_context io_context;
std::string hostname, protocol;

// Resolve host
asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
asio::ip::basic_resolver<asio::ip::tcp>::results_type result = resolver.resolve(hostname, protocol);
// Connect
asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_context);
asio::connect(socket, result);
```

Hopefully this help others!